# Difference between the verbs used in the main clause of 間 and 間に

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, verbs, particle-に

I saw these two sentences in a Youtube video-
私は冬休みの間韓国へ行きました。
私は冬休みの間に韓国へ行きました。
Shouldn't the first sentence be-
私は冬休みの間韓国へ行っていました。

My question is that shouldn't we use ています form of verbs with 間?( to indicate state of doing something the whole time)

Answer (score 2):

冬休みの間韓国へ行きました indicates that you have been to Korea for the entirety of the winter vacation, whereas 冬休みの間に韓国へ行きました means you went to Korea for some time, up to the entire winter vacation time (but not necessarily). Both are correct forms.

There are situations only one will work. E.g. you can say 水を飲む間じっとしていた、but not 水を飲む間にじっとしていた because じっとしている implies entirety.

Comment: 私は冬休みの間韓国へ行っていました。So is this sentence correct?